# Why does ReSharper suggest I convert a for loop into a LINQ expression?

Tags: c#, linq, for-loop, resharper

In Visual Studio Re-Sharper keeps recommending I convert a for loop to a linq expression but what is the reason for this?

Which is faster?

Here are some example loops where resharper suggests a linq conversion:

```
foreach (XmlNode legendEntryNode in _legendEntryNodes)
{
    var xmlElement = legendEntryNode["FeatureType"];

    if (xmlElement == null || !xmlElement.InnerText.Equals(featuretype)) continue;

    var xmlNodeList = legendEntryNode.SelectNodes("Themes/Theme");

    if (xmlNodeList != null)

    foreach (XmlNode themeNode in xmlNodeList)
    {
        var element = themeNode["Value"];

        if (element == null || !element.InnerText.Equals(v)) continue;

        var xmlElement1 = themeNode["Icon"];

        if (xmlElement1 != null)
        {
            string iconname = "<ms:ICON>" + xmlElement1.InnerText + "</ms:ICON>";

            var element1 = themeNode["Highlight"];

            if (element1 != null)
            {
                string highlightname = "<ms:HIGHLIGHT>" + element1.InnerText + "</ms:HIGHLIGHT>";
                gml = gml.Insert(c, iconname + highlightname);

                c += (iconname.Length + highlightname.Length);
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

And this simpler example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < getPointsRequest.Attribs.Length; i++)
{
    string attribName = getPointsRequest.Attribs[i].AttributeName;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(attribName))
    {
        sqlQuery += "<ms:" + attribName + ">||\"" + attribName + "\"||</ms:" + attribName + ">";
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to show us an example loop.

Comment: Just a minor little thing, I know these are examples but you might want to change the string concatenations to `string.Format` so the simple example becomes: `sqlQuery += string.Format("<ms:{0}>||\"{0}\"||</ms:{0}>", attribName);`, which is easier to read. Resharper makes it easy to change them as it is one of it's refactoring options.

Comment: (btw, backticks for code-formatting don't work in the question title, unfortunately)

Comment: You might also want to use a StringBuilder instead of the "sqlQuery += " string concatenation.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Speed is very often irrelevant in large portions of your code - you should write code the *simplest* way, and then measure it to make sure it's *fast enough*.

If your for loop is really just querying, then LINQ is *absolutely* a great way to end up with more readable code. It's not universally applicable, but it's something you should at least *bear in mind* frequently.

Quite often a for loop can be converted into a query to be evaluated lazily, and then a foreach loop which performs some action on each value returned by the query. That can help separate the two aspects, letting you focus on one at a time when reading the code. It's important to keep LINQ queries *as* queries though, rather than using side-effects within them - it's designed to have a functional approach, which really doesn't mix pleasantly with side-effects.

If you have some concrete examples, we could give more opinions about which loops would make sense to convert to use LINQ, and which wouldn't.

Comment: I would have assumed that although speed of a simple loop may seem irrelevant but surely all these irrelevant places add up to one big difference in performance in the grand scheme of things?

Comment: @CSharpened: That's a big assumption, and one which you should validate before trying to micro-optimize everywhere. Often performance is far more affected by *architecture* and overall design than the individual bits of code, and bottlenecks are also often in IO rather than processing. You should decide what your performance requirements are, measure the performance of the clearest code which meets your needs, then *if* you need to optimize, do so in a targeted way using a profiler. I certainly wouldn't assume that all areas of code contribute uniformly to the overall performance.

Comment: Ok thanks for that. Appreciate it. Being a relatively new developer compared to many I sometimes overlook things like that as often I get tasked with a small portion of a project and as such want to ensure that my part runs as smoothly and quickly as possible while still meeting the requirements 100%.

Comment: @CSharpened: If you're working as part of a bigger team, you should ask your team-mates what the performance requirements are for your part of the project. They may well not have considered it - you should tactfully suggest that benchmarking the whole system would be useful, and profiling which areas are bottlenecks if the overall performance isn't satisfactory.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will certainly keep it in mind if performance is an issue at any point. What do you use to benchmark your code?

Comment: ANTS Performance Profiler is the best tool I've used. You can try it with free trial and you'll probably love it. Unless you already use it because this post is 2 years old ;).

Comment: I must be the only person who finds linq less readable than for loops. Too much assembler and C code for me, not enough SQL

Comment: @rolls: You may not be the only one, but I suspect you're rare in that... and possibly just haven't given LINQ enough of a chance. It takes a little while to get into the mindset, but it's then *enormously* useful. I'd encourage you to at least try it a bit more.

Comment: Oh I definitely do use it, however I still use for/foreach loops regularly as well, especially for low level stuff. I'm sure most C programmers are similar to me, most of them probably never touch java/C# so they probably don't even know what they are let alone if they are readable.

Answer (score 18):

No performance gain as such, but some benefits

- Makes code more readable.
- Reduces the number of lines.
- Easy to maintain.
- In some cases you don't require temporary variables, which you might require in for loop. Using Linq you can chain queries.

For more details you can refer:

- [LINQ query operators: lose that foreach already](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/05/09/linq-query-operators-lose-that-foreach-already/)
- [The “Anti-For” Campaign](http://weblogs.asp.net/podwysocki/archive/2009/06/26/the-anti-for-campaign.aspx)
- [Life After Loops](http://www.codethinked.com/life-after-loops)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: one would prefer to write a code closer to natural language... apparently, LINQ helps doing so...

Answer (score 6):

In general ReSharper's suggestions are just suggestions and no warnings. So it's only up to you to decide what way you go: LINQ or foreach.
I have the same issue with suggestion "Use 'var'". I click that suggestion only if I think the reader could better read the statement.
Readability is one of my highest priorities while writing code.

Answer (score 4):

It's probable that there's no difference in speed, however using Linq can often result in terser code.
That's not to say you should always accept R#'s suggestion to convert to a Linq expression.  Sometimes complex but understandable foreach loops are converted into valid but not easily understood Linq expressions.

Comment: Technically a for loop is always faster since a linq expression requires method invocations.

Comment: This is one of the main issues I have with it. I am not really up to speed with linq and as a result I find some of the converted code difficult to read which actually has the opposite effect that resharper is most likely intending. I suspect this would be the same with other devs who do not use linq too and may make portions of my code difficult to read to those picking it up that aren't up to speed with linq either.

Comment: The whole point of linq is to have less terse, more readable code - that it may be terse in some cases is either the exceptional case or a failure of the reader to appreciate functional/declarative code. You basically never want to write linq code like this as a foreach loop: from s in selection.ShapeRange.Cast<Shape>() where s.IsSomething() select s.Name

Answer (score 4):

I'd say there is a reason why not to convert sometimes. It is perhaps less admirable that ReSharper does not offer a refactoring to convert a LINQ expression (back) into a for-loop. I have on a few occasions converted a loop into an expression and then later wanted to put in some further actions (often debugging actions) within the loop; I have to convert them back by hand.

I would warn against converting a for-loop without good reason. Quite often it really doesn't improve readability, and there isn't any other strong reason to do it (as others have rightly pointed out, most loops are not speed critical).

I think some for-loops are more readable than the LINQ equivalent, because they visually break down the actions of the loop into bite-size pieces. I'd say that it tends to be small loops (three or four lines) that are most improved by making them into an expression on one line.

[Sorry this post is mostly opinion, but readability is a bit of a subjective subject. No trolling!]

Answer (score 2):

Hi Linq is actually calling a for loop internally. I guess it comes downs to that Linq expressions are in general easier to read/ maintain. If you are really concerned about performance there is a good comparison between the two: http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/04/23/c-linq-vs-foreach---round-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As reference for others, here is an example of for loop and a for loop suggested by Resharper

```
for (int x = 0; x < grid.Length; x++)
        {
            var intCount = grid[x].Select((a, b) => new {Value = a, Index = b})
                .GroupBy(y => y.Value)
                .Where(y => y.Count() > 1).Select(item => item.Key).ToArray();

            if (intCount.Count() > 1)
                return false;
        }
```

To explain this code, this for loop will get all the duplicates on an array. After getting all the duplicates, check if count of items are greater than one, then return false.

This is the suggested for loop in LINQ:

```
  return grid.Select(t => t.Select((a, b) => new {Value = a, Index = b}).
            GroupBy(y => y.Value).Where(y => y.Count() > 1).
            Select(item => item.Key).ToArray()).All(intCount => intCount.Count() <= 1);
```

There might be no performance gains, but as you can see from the example, a LINQ query is cleaner, easy to read, lesser lines (which in this case, only one line of code, I just adjusted it after pasting it here) and easy to debug as well.